# Exclude part of webpage from being cached?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, caching, varnish

I'm using apache, varnish and w3 total cache on a wordpress site.

I have a range of random posts that get loaded into an element.

My page is being cached by varnish and there for this element loses its randomness, ideally I would like to exclude this element from varnish and any other cache if this means editing my apache.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using JS to load the element, and add a varnish VCL pass for the URL that is called by AJAX for the element.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I'm looking for, thanks. I'll have a look at this VCL pass, if it all goes well I'll give you a tick.